# Updating multiple forms in JSF

Tags: forms, jsf

Hello I have something like that:

```
<h:form id="firstForm">
 here i have some input fields
</h:form>
<h:form id="secondForm">
  here i have some input fields
</h:form>
<h:form id="thirdForm">
<p:commandButton id="completeOne" type="button"
                                        value="Complete">
                                        </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

my question is, by pressing the Complete button how i can update the forms: firstForm and secondForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To indicate which components should be updated (i.e. receive new HTML) by an AJAX request, there is the aptly named attribute `update` :-).

In your case, if you want `firstForm`and `secondForm` to be updated by the CommandButton, use:

```
<p:commandButton id="completeOne"
    type="button" value="Complete" update="firstForm secondForm">
</p:commandButton>
```

This is described in the PrimeFaces docs:

> AJAX and Non-AJAX
>
> CommandButton  has  built-in  ajax  capabilities,  ajax  submit  is 
>   enabled  by  default  and  configured using `ajax` attribute. When
>   ajax attribute is set to false, form is submitted with a regular full
>   page refresh.
>
> The `update` attribute  is  used  to  partially  update  other 
>   component(s)  after  the  ajax  response  is received. Update
>   attribute takes a comma or white-space separated list of JSF component
>   ids to be updated. Basically any JSF component, not just PrimeFaces
>   components should be updated with the Ajax  response.

*[PrimeFaces User Guide 6.0](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf)*

The default for the `update` attribute is `@form`, meaning only the form containing the component is updated. In your case that would be `thirdForm`, 
which is not enough.

---

*Note:*

Plain JSF (i.e. without PrimeFaces) has a similar attribute for the [`f:ajax` tag](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html), which indicates which components are to be updated. However, for `f:ajax` it is called `render`, not `update`. It's easy to confuse the two, especially if you mix plain JSF and PrimeFaces tags.